# MY SQL Partition by order by and percents

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, partition, percentile

[image]

Can anyone explain each step in more detail of the attached syntax.  I can gather somewhat what the query and subquery is trying to find half the p1s when length is less then half and then when it is more. I just cant decipher understand the why and how. Is this similar to rank()OVER but using values inputted like length instead also not sure where the x1 and x2 come into play is that what its being called or its alias. Is the first query pulling the p1 from the subquery I get confused when and when you can not use aliases as well.  I apologize for the rambling the more coherent and detailed in layman terms the better.  Thank you in advance for your knowledge its much obliged!

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: `x1` and `x2` are aliases, those assign a name to the column in the resultset.  We typically include the optional `AS` keyword before the column alias, not because it makes any difference to MySQL, but primarily as an aid to the future reader. The same thing for the `p1` and `p2` in the inline view query.  If we run just the inline view query, we can see that it returns columns named `p1` and `p2`. the outer query sees the resultset from the inline view query like a table, with columns named rating, length, p1, p2